# How can I derive an array of integer keys to a single string column in data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm designing a data flow where one of my sources, named "**ApiSource**", contains information retrieved from an Api. One of **ApiSource**'s columns is named "**genre_ids**", which is an array of integers.

I want to look up the string equivalent of each id contained in the array, concatenate them, and store the result as a single string in a derived column named "**genre**".

The string equivalents should be looked up in another source named "**GenreSource**" which contains 2 columns: "**id**" and "**name**".

So, for example:

Let's assume **GenreSource**'s dataset is

```
[{id: 1, name: "Action"}, {id: 2, name: "Strategy"}, {id: 3, name: "Horror"}]
```

If a row in **ApiSource** is

```
{title: "Resident Evil 2", genre_ids : [1,3]}
```

The desired result is

```
{title: "Resident Evil 2", genre_ids : [1,3], genre: "Action|Horror"}
```

How can I achieve this?